# RecyclerView get the clicked item details - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to android. I am trying to create a `RecyclerView` using [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-complex-lists-with-the-android-recyclerview/) tutorial. The `RecyclerView` works fine. My problem is, I want to get the title and description of the clicked item of the `RecyclerView`.

Can someone help me? [Here](https://github.com/sathyabaman/Jaffna-temples-new) is my full code.

### Updated

```
    public class View_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        CardView cv;
        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        ImageView imageView;


        View_Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            //added by me
            title.setOnClickListener(this);
            description.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //added by me

        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return imageView;
        }
        public TextView getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
        public TextView getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // Toast.makeText(get, "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
            Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(getLayoutPosition()));
            Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(this.getTitle()));
            Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(this.getDescription()));
           // getLayoutPosition(); //no method like that
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecyclerView onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the ViewHolder View Objects to get details like below.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   // Toast.makeText(get, "CLICK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()));
    Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(getLayoutPosition()));
    Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(title.getText());
    Log.i("positon-of-clicked-item", String.valueOf(sescription.getText()));
   // getLayoutPosition(); //no method like that
}
```

Comment: Hy. Tnx this is what i was Expecting.

Comment: you are welcome. By the way you should try bind data item to ViewHolder for better handling click and states for RecyclerView Items. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265865/recyclerview-causes-issue-when-recycling/35266327#35266327

Answer (score 1):

Call `getAdapterPosition()` inside `onClick()`, then with the position get item from the list you are populating.

**Update :**

Easiest way is that you put your `ViewHolder` inside your adapter class. Then you can access `List<Data>` of your adapter.

Comment: hy tnx , am able get the clicked position. but can you help me to get the title for the clicked position also. Tried but don't work. i have updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple good related posts/writeups on this at the below links:

- [Why doesn't RecyclerView have onItemClickListener()? And how RecyclerView is different from Listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif)
- http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/
- https://gist.github.com/grantland/cd70814fe4ac369e3e92

The solution is easy to code but not something that becomes immediately apparent if you're new to using the RecyclerView.

In your View_Holder class, you need to do 2 things:

1. In the constructor for the view holder, pass a reference to your adapter(or whatever you want to respond to the click) and store it.  There are examples of this in the above links.
2. Override the **onClick** method to respond to the click event for the selected item. Then in the **onClick** method, make a call to the **getAdapterPosition()** method to retrieve the position of the current item in the cursor used to power the adapter.  Then call a method you define in the adapter class you passed a reference to in step 1 and pass the needed position of the cursor to that method as a parameter.

In the method that you call from the onClick event, you'll need to look up the information you want from the cursor.