# How to change ImageButton in RecyclerView row in android (like in twitter app)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I tried to change the `ImageButton` background (like in Twitter app )  but if I change the `ImageButton` in first row then in some other row the `ImageButton` will also be changed.

And also I need to keep the changed `ImageButton` background in multiple rows as it is.

**And I refered this link**

[RecyclerView causes issue when recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265865/recyclerview-causes-issue-when-recycling)

But in the above link solution is there for :

1. To select only one row at a time (As in Navigation drawer ).
2. And the other solution will cause the problem I mentioned.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to store the button state somewhere for each of your item. And then in `onBindViewHolder()` set the appropriate background for the button. If you show your adapter code it would be easier to help with the code.

Comment: learn how RecyclerView works, you have to keep state of your view in your model.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview) you can find a clear and fast example about recycler view. Say that
you should work on **onBindViewHolder** overrided function.

Store image information and then apply it every time onBindViewHolder is triggered.

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    Object yourItem = items.get(position);

    ImageView yourImageView = viewHolder.yourImageView ;

    if(yourItem.containsDifferentImage()){
       yourImageViewsetImageResource(R.drawable.my_new_image);
    }
    else{
       yourImageViewsetImageResource(R.drawable.my_standard_image);
    }

}
```